# How do you call XCTest in a Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, xctest, swift-playground

I was looking at Bendyworks' article on Unit testing  with Swift: http://bendyworks.com/unit-testing-in-swift/

and as you do with Swift I took the code and threw it in Playground to have poke at it.

```
import Cocoa

class Firewood {
    var charred: Bool
    init()  {
        println("initializing our firewood")
        charred = false
    }
    func burn() {
        charred = true
    }
}

import XCTest
class SimpleFirewoodTests: XCTestCase {
    func testBurningActuallyChars() {
        let firewood = Firewood()
        firewood.burn()
        assert(firewood.charred, "should be charred after burning")
    }
}
```

But then of course you cannot press the test button as well Playground is a continuous REPL, so you need to know how to call the tests, does someone know the inside of XCTest to know what to call to do a test run?

Comment: just make a project... playground isn't for everything

Comment: Bosh. No unit testing means playgrounds are off limits for test-driven development, and that would be a load of malarkey. I for one look forward to being able to write tests in a playground.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a full example, which works in Swift 3+, which shows you how to do this. This is nice because now you can use XCTAssert and then they are easily directly moved to your real test bundle once you get the kinks worked out. 
    import XCTest

```
class MyTestCase: XCTestCase {

   func testExample() {
       print("Test1")
       XCTAssertTrue(true)
   }

   func testAnother() {
       print("Test2")
       XCTAssertFalse(false)
   }
}

MyTestCase.defaultTestSuite().run() // Swift 3
MyTestCase.defaultTestSuite.run() // Swift 4
```

This is how it will look like:

[image]

Unfortunately you have to open the log window to see whether it passed or failed. It would be nice if you could see the test results colorized...

Comment: Thanks for this! As of Swift 4, `defaultTestSuite` is a property and doesn’t take the parens after.

Answer (score 13):

I've just written a blog post explaining how you can do this in Xcode 7, along with a sample Playground which will run Unit Tests. The short answer is, you can create a small test runner object within the playground which runs the tests and reports on the results. Along with an observer to catch failed tests, you can get a pretty good TDD setup with a playground.

http://initwithstyle.net/2015/11/tdd-in-swift-playgrounds/
https://github.com/sshrpe/TDDSwiftPlayground

Comment: I checked out your repo and can confirm this works great! However, if I create a new playground and manually import your boilerplate code, I'm getting the following error: Playground execution failed: /var/folders/r1/n32p3rzd07l50rnj6vjny6zd06mc_r/T/./lldb/516/playground63.swift:1:8: error: cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'
import XCTest - anything I'm missing, or something special to do with the playground initialization?

Comment: I've discovered the reason for this: something I missed along the way, it seems this method of importing XCTest is only working for Mac OS X Playgrounds, not for iOS. On iOS playgrounds XCTest can't be imported (if anyone can figure out why that would be awesome).

Answer (score 5):

XCTest is currently not supported in playgrounds. If this is something that you'd like, I'd encourage you to file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com requesting it.

Comment: Radar filed: <rdar://24684347> Swift Playgrounds: "import XCTest" gives "cannot load underlying module for 'XCTest'"

Comment: As of Xcode 8, Swift 3.0.1, @Stuart Sharpe's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33583295/1107226) works in an iOS playground.

Answer (score 5):

Running tests in playground now works by invoking run() on the defaultTestSuite of your tests class:

```
let testSuite = SimpleFirewoodTests.defaultTestSuite()
testSuite.run()
```

NB: the assert in your test should be replaced with XCTAssertEqual.